# Why isn't the LED flashing?

Tags: schematics, 555

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXkOPP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have this schematic that I need to convert to a circuit using Tinkercad. At the moment, the LED turns on but it does not flash and I can not figure out why.

[Here is the tinkercad Link](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/9vfNMPHPj78-powerful-wolt/editel?sharecode=XR0_6-ivukTeMmD-mae1-jJSDTIF9HZcuhMV7WoNNfQ)

Schematic:

[image]

Circuit:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and insert the schematic directly into the question rather than linking to an external site.  Stack Exchange hosts its own images.

Comment: You might want to consider avoiding 555’s when it can be done much simpler https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313415/rc-circuit-as-clock-source/313420#313420 then subst. The same RC values 10uF 51k

Comment: Pin 1 (GND) of the 555 looks like it is going to the wrong side of the capacitor

Comment: Ive fixed the 555 to ground issue and it doesnt seem to have changed anything

Comment: The ratio of your resistor values determine the on time vs the off time. Your 1k off time is so small that the LED appears to be on all the time.

Comment: @Audioguru The cap discharges through 51k, not 1k.

Comment: Looks like your schematic and 'breadboard' diagram are apple and orange. Re-check the connections.

Comment: it all looks good to me, perhaps you have the wrong resistor in r2

Comment: @ Mitsu Raj No, the capacitor charges slowly through 52k (with the LED turned on) then the capacitor discharges very quickly through 1k with the LED turned off for such a short off duration that it appears to be turned on all the time.

Comment: @Audioguru I am afraid it's actually the otherway. R2 for discharging and R1+R2 for charging. https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_oscillator.html

Comment: I see that the LED off-time should be almost the same as the LED on-time. Then if the parts are good the breadboard must have an intermittent contact.

Answer (score 1):

Your 555 isn't grounded. The only connection to ground in the entire circuit is the one connecting the LED to ground, and the 555 isn't connected to that. At least if your cartoon diagram is anything to go by.